# InfoPath Approval Fields, certain users can fill in some fields

Tags: infopath, approval-process

Using Infopath, I would like to have a "Approval Status" field that only certain users (the managers) can see when approving or rejecting a form. The scenario would be the following:

User fills out an item in a list which triggers a workflow that notifies both the initiator that they sent in a request and a manager that a request has been made. The form submitted has an option to select what manager you are submitting your form to for approval.

That manager would then be able to go to the form and select "Approved" or "Rejected" from a drop down. The original user wouldn't have seen that field when filling out the form originally.

Any way to make this happen? Few options? Other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit on your form design. If the manager's name is stored in the form, then you can create a section with the approval field and hide that section when the current user and the manager are not the same person.